# How can I tell where the enemy is in COD to avoid getting shot?

Tags: call-of-duty-series

When I play Assassin's Creed, I can turn on eagle vision and see all the enemies. This obviously makes it easier to kill them.

But when I play Call of Duty, I'm always getting shot by some guy haven't seen. I think this has something to do with how I move. I've read books like The Art of War and they always say like you shouldn't just run out in the middle of a clearing and things like that. This is probably obvious to most gamers but I'm a pretty uneducated gamer as far as battle tactics.

Can someone give me some tips on how I can avoid getting shot? Could simply adjusting my positioning and moving more carefully around help? If so how do I do that?

Comment: Good headphones (not earbuds!) help tremendously in hearing other players approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try keeping up to speed on what’s going on around your character. And I’m not just talking about what’s happening in his or her direct line of sight. I’m talking sides and backs, too. So, you know, use your eyes for what they’re supposed to be used for.

Don’t lock your gaze into a forward position. Make a habit out of throwing quick looks to the sides while moving. Sometimes you should do a 180, just to see what’s going on behind you.

---

The Minimap is there for you to use it. It gives you vital information (for your character, that is) on a lot of what’s going on in the game. Learn to give it a glimpse or two at quick intervals.

Just don’t get stuck in doctoral studies of it. The minimap mustn’t steal your attention from what’s happening on the screen otherwise.

---

Don't rush. Cool it down. When you’re running, you miss more of what’s going on in the game. And you usually die more often, too. Like when sprinting around the corner where Mr. Camper of the Year is expecting you with the barrel pointed at your head.

---

Lay down! The smaller you’re able to make your character, the harder it’ll be to be hit by your opponents.

No, we don’t have a pill for shrinking. But there’s other stuff you can do.

Hide behind cover, so that as little as possible of your character is visible, or go prone. And do it often.

---

Reload in COVER. Don't reload if you've just killed a character. You hurry to reload, even though the clip’s practically full. Cause someone told you once that you should reload between each kill.

Suddenly, that dead dude’s buddy shows up. Bang! Your character can now be found lifeless on the ground.

Why?

Well, because you can’t cancel the reloading animation to shoot. And that animation usually takes a couple of seconds. These seconds tend to be enough time for that hostile to kill your character.

Wait to reload. Either ‘til you’re safely behind cover. Or ‘til you’re sure that the character you just killed off doesn’t have mates lurking about.

Conscious of how many rounds you’ve got left in your mag after each gun fight. If your clip’s more than half full, you’ll be able to take out at least one more character before a reload becomes necessary.

---

The enemy’s air support is no joke. Stay on guard when hostiles call in choppers or drones.

If possible, you should move your character indoors.

The exception to this rule is of course if you find yourself with launchers in hand to shoot down the airborne threat.

---

Use Dropshots. It’s a highly effective technique when performed correctly.

Fundamentally, the technique consists of two parts:

When meeting an opponent you quickly go from standing position to prone.
You fire your weapon, the whole way down, from standing to lying position.
How well the technique works is determined by how quickly you manage to go prone and how good you are at hitting your opponent heading down.

---

JUMP! Jumping can save your characters life.If you manage to jump while being fired at, you can reduce the number of bullets that reach your character. Cause you’ll just scadoodle right over them.

If you manage to return fire while midair, the odds increase considerably in your favor.

Jumping while shooting’s obviously been coined The Jump Shot.

*These were just a few tips that’ll let you live longer and die less in COD multiplayer. I know there are a lot of other things you can do.*

Comment: Now that's what I'm talkin about. Thanks for the tips man.

Comment: You could add 'elephanting'. This is a term used by professional gamers and indicates a player constantly sprinting. Sprinting in game makes more noice then walking or crouching so other players may be able to hear you running from the other side of the wall and just wait for you to run around the corner. They will then have the upper hand since they were expecting you.

Comment: +1, but use jumping with care. It puts you on a very predictable trajectory, which, if your opponent has any skill, only makes you easier to kill. It's only really effective if you need that extra 1/2 second to get the kill shot, or there's cover very close by that you can jump behind. Otherwise stick to drop.

Comment: Correction: You can cancel the reload animation. If you switch to your secondary and quickly back to your primary you cancel the reload. Just tapping Y/Triangle/1-2 on the respective consoles will cancel the animation.

Comment: In addition to the slow down tip, if you hear gunfire near by and are expecting to be in a fight soon, stop sprinting.  If you sprint all the way to the battle, you will likely be dead or almost dead before you can stop the sprinting animation and aim your gun.  You're better off walking the last 30 feet or so, weapon ready, then getting their twice as fast and dying immediately.

Comment: Jumping should be used sparingly. Like CodeMoose said, it puts you on a predictable trajectory, but the act of the jump itself can be unexpected and throw off aim for a split second. That said, if you jump a lot, that's more time you're in the air and can't control your own movement, which means you can only watch while someone takes aim at you. Also, try to keep your crosshairs at eye or upper-chest level while you move. This makes it more likely that when you turn to face someone, you're already lined up for a headshot or a good burst to the chest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best tip i could give you is check your minimap often. Its in the top right cornor and will show you enemys nearby based on where they have fired recently (unless they have a scilencer) Also if its advanced warfare you can see exo movement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the minimap, check your corners, don't rush into open spaces, stay close to cover and know you're surroundings, in games like COD experience is key, which means that the longer you'll play, the better you'll become, eventually you're reflexes should also adjust to your sensetivity and your response time will get better.

Keep playing and find the playstyle that suits you, practice makes perfect, you'll get better as you play!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, The Art Of War is a philosophical treatise on grand warfare or "stratagem", meaning strategic, not operational or tactical warfare. There is information in it that will help you in many other situations (such as this), like the notion of strength and position. But it is not really what you should try to study for playing COD.

Secondly, COD is a pure videogame. Not really a realistic representation of tactical combat. Therefore only the very basic rules apply to the game.

These basic rules are the same for any simplified setting such as this... They are the same in Quake3 as in COD and they are quite simple. Since these are game rules we can liken COD to a shooting gallery game at the fair. Only it is a double ended one, where the targets can fire back at you.

Now, using this mental image, we can dissect what we need to master to win.

First, hitting the targets. This is about trajectory and speed. You need to learn the targets movement, how they move and at what speed. This way you can predict where they will go.

Second, range, learning to determine the range of a target

Third, threat assessment, figuring out IF a certain target is about to shoot you, or if it is likely to be just moving. Are the target in range to successfully target you? In the case of unseen targets, based on your experience are there likely to be hidden targets at this point in time? If so where? Now this is experience based, but the basics are the same for any game like this.

Fourth, making yourself harder to hit, if the targets are going to fire at you, make sure they have a hard time hitting you. This involves presenting a small hit area. So keep crouched, stay behind things and also run away to increase range, as in 3d space range makes you smaller to the attacker.

Fifth, movement, now use the above to position yourself so that you limit a targets ability to do the same. Meaning move to positions where targets may not use obstacles or range to limit their hit area size.

Sixth, situational awareness, look around you in 3d space all the time. Keep track of movement. Do not follow every moving target by moving towards it (remember, range) but register its trajectory in your mind, anticipate where it is going.

Seventh, keep moving. A moving target is harder to track down. Move in erratic patterns. Do unexpected things. This breaks the cycle that your targets will try to fit you to.

Most importantly - COD is a simple game, like most shooters. It is based on simple rules and reflexes and thus can be mastered like any simpler skill based game, with training. So training is key.